# electron - acceder a la webcam

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, firefox

para utilizar la webcam desde mi aplicacion hecha en electron he utilizado el modulo node webcamjs, este es el codigo que utilice, tomado de la doc del propio modulo:

```
<h1>camara</h1>
<div id="my_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
<div id="my_result"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
function take_snapshot() {
    Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
        document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
    } );
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

Cuando intento a acceder a la webcam electron me lanza la siguiente excepción:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: take_snapshot is not defined*

Sin embargo, cuando el mismo código lo pruebo desde `firefox`, funciona bien, `firefox` anuncia que se intenta acceder a la `webcam` y se le da OK para completar la acción. 
Por otra parte, desde `Google Chrome` parece que esto no esta permitido pues me dice:

> Webcam.js error: Webcam is not loaded yet.

Alguna sugerencia entonces para utilizar la cámara desde `electron`, o por que `Google Chrome` tiene este comportamiento?

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Revisando la web oficial de la librería que utilizas https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs hay algo a tener en cuenta:
En `Google Chrome` requiere `HTTPS` y a menos que tengas un dominio con dicho protocolo, no funcionará. Puedes conseguir un certificado `SSL` gratuito en https://www.startssl.com/ o en https://letsencrypt.org/

```
WebcamJS has been tested on the following browsers / operating systems:
OS  Browser     Notes
**Mac OS X  Chrome 30+  Works -- Chrome 47+ requires HTTPS**
Mac OS X    Firefox 20+     Works
Mac OS X    Safari 6+   Requires Adobe Flash Player
**Windows   Chrome 30+  Works -- Chrome 47+ requires HTTPS**
Windows     Firefox 20+     Works
Windows     IE 9    Requires Adobe Flash Player
Windows     IE 10   Requires Adobe Flash Player
Windows     IE 11   Requires Adobe Flash Player
```

Answer (score 0):

electron se compone de: librería electron + node + chromium.

Dado que webcamjs en Chrome (derivado de chromium) requiere HTTPS como bien dice @fredyfx no te va a ser posible usarlo directamente

En este hilo aclaran que siendo chromium no necesitas webcamJS y podes usar directamente el API getUserMedia de HTML5:

WebCam js not starting using electron-build on windows. #243
https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/243

> Also, I should point out that since you are using Electron, you have Chromium built right into your app, so you don't really need WebcamJS. You could just use the HTML5 getUserMedia API directly, and you can be assured it will be available on all platforms, thanks to Chromium/Electron.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
https://simpl.info/getusermedia/

siguiendo links llegas al tutorial de HTML5 getusermedia

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/